# How to add a string to an array?

Tags: reactjs

```js
const [userOrderCollection, setUserOrderCollection] = useState([{
  url: null
}]);

const onAddedUserOrder = url => {
  if (userOrderCollection[0].url === url) return;
  else {
    setUserOrderCollection([{ ...userOrderCollection,
      url
    }]);
    console.log(userOrderCollection)
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But, the line is added only once, and with the first click, I get an empty array in the console, only with the second click the addition is triggered ...

Comment: I'm not sure what your state is representing. Can you try to explain a bit more what this code is meant to be doing?

Comment: I have a list with users, and when I click on them, I add links to their avatars to the array to understand which users are selected, and then send this array to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually adding anything to the array, you're constantly creating an array of a single element. In addition your console log will not show the updated state at that point.

Try this:

```js
const [userOrderCollection, setUserOrderCollection] = useState([]);

const onAddedUserOrder = url => {
  if (userOrderCollection.find(user => user.url === url)) return;
  else {
    setUserOrderCollection(prev => ([ ...prev, { url } ]));
  }
};
```

If you want to see the state after it's been updated you should do so within a `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

State is updated on the next render of the component, so logging it where you do will show the previous state

Answer (score 0):

You can't console.log right after calling the `setUserOrderCollection` function since it's asynchronous, calling that function only dispatches the action to take place on a later date.

On another note, to avoid race conditions, you should use the `set*((value) => newValue)` instead of `set*(newValue)`.

```js
setUserOrderCollection(userOrderCollection => [{ ...userOrderCollection,
      url
}]);
```

Also, if you want to add something to the array you should use something like that:

```js
setUserOrderCollection(userOrderCollection => [...userOrderCollection, {
      url
}]);
```

Your code would only expand an array over the only object in an array, which probably isn't something you're looking for.

To log each state change you can use the `useEffect` hook, like this:

```js
useEffect(() => console.log(userOrderCollection),
    [ userOrderCollection ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the array destruction wrong:

Change

```
setUserOrderCollection([{ ...userOrderCollection,
  url
}]);
```

to

```
setUserOrderCollection([
  ...userOrderCollection,
  {url}
]);
```